# How to fix the cardheader view in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating an angular application in which i have an detail page with a cardheader which consist of two buttons namely back and edit and both sides and a text in between.
I have used bootstap and set the columns like below.
[image]

But when i see the screen in mobile view the header is not aligned properly

[image]

Below is the code i am using. How could i fix it to view in a single line in mobile view

```
<div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 text-left">
          <button size="sm" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goBack()">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>&nbsp; Back
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
          <h4>Switch Detail</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 text-right">
          <button size="sm" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="gotoEdit()">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp; Edit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could hide the button text and leave only the icons on mobile view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of approach you can follow.

1. You could force the width of the container to stay constant on all views. Note that this can cause your text to overflow.

```
<div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 text-left">
          <button size="sm" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goBack()">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>&nbsp; <span class="button-text"> Back 
          </span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-center">
          <h4>Switch Detail</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-right">
          <button size="sm" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="gotoEdit()">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp; <span class="button-text"> Edit </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

2. You could use `@media` Query to hide the text on the buttons leaving only the icons on a mobile view.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  button-text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

3. Alternatively, you could reduce the font size of the title on mobile using the same approach in case 2 above.